# Multi Value Dictionary Enumeration

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to implement MultiValueDictionary on my own in C#. I have a problem with implementing IEnumerable.

I used `IDictionary<K, HashSet<V>>` as internal structure.
I assign enumerators from dictionary and hash sets to fields and I try to traverse them. The problem is: `_keysEnum.Current.Value` is always null and every time I got empty collection. The internal dictionary contains correct values in hash sets.

```
public class MultiValueDictionaryEnumerator<K, V> : IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, V>>
{
    private IDictionary<K, HashSet<V>> _dict;
    private IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, HashSet<V>>> _keysEnum;
    private HashSet<V>.Enumerator _setEnum;
    private bool _setEnumInit;

    public MultiValueDictionaryEnumerator(IDictionary<K, HashSet<V>> dict)
    {
        _dict = dict;
        Reset();
    }
    public KeyValuePair<K, V> Current => KeyValuePair.Create(_keysEnum.Current.Key, _setEnum.Current);

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        var result = false;
        if (_setEnumInit)
        {
            result = _setEnum.MoveNext();
            if (!result)
            {
                result = _keysEnum.MoveNext();
                if (result)
                {
                    _setEnum = _keysEnum.Current.Value.GetEnumerator();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _keysEnum = _dict.GetEnumerator();
        if (_keysEnum.Current.Value != null)
        {
            _setEnum = _keysEnum.Current.Value.GetEnumerator();
            _setEnumInit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a custom IEnumerator instead of using Linq to produce the desired enumeration of KeyValuePairs with the individual values from the HashSets? Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: You don’t need to manually implement an enumerator. In your main class where you have your GetEnumerator method either use Linq like elgonzo said or just iterate over your data and do `yield return` and the compiler will automatically create an enumerator for you. For details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield#iterator-methods-and-get-accessors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, using an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators). Implementing the `IEnumerator<T>` interface explicitly is too cumbersome.

```
public class MultiValueDictionary<K, V> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>
{
    private IDictionary<K, HashSet<V>> _dict;

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, V>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var entry in _dict)
        {
            var hashSet = entry.Value;
            foreach (var item in hashSet)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(entry.Key, item);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```